# Displaying a list of users using a for statement

Tags: shell, unix

I am making 'Welcome program'.
but I have a problem to display the results.

```
for who in $( who | wc -l)
do
 echo "$(who | cut -d' ' -f1) is here."
done
```

Debugging is success. but When I display the result,

```
202020954
202020897
201821100 is here.
```

there's something problem in `echo`.

I want to display the results like

```
202020954 is here.
202020897 is here
201821100 is here.
```

Any reply is thankful. Best regards.

Comment: `who | cut -d' ' -f1` will print multiple lines. Why use a for loop like that, though? You’ll call `who` _many_ times, and there’s nothing in your code to actually iterate the lines it prints, just call it again as many times as the number of words it prints.

Answer (score 0):

If you're coding in bash, then you can slurp the `who` output into an array

```sh
readarray -t names < <(who | cut -d' ' -f1)
```

then you don't need a loop for printing:

```sh
printf "%s is here.\n" "${names[@]}"
```